# html5 canvas circle palette

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, color-palette

i have source with circle palette, problem is palette have static size 250px x 250px, i need smaller 200px x 200px. At first sight code looks like messy, but don't need analyze converter functions like: `HSB2RGB, RGB2HSB` and etc.

```js
    function HSB2RGB(j, d, c) {
        var e, g, l, h, k, b, a, m;
        if (c == 0) {
            return [0, 0, 0]
        }
        j *= 0.016666667;
        d *= 0.01;
        c *= 0.01;
        h = Math.floor(j);
        k = j - h;
        b = c * (1 - d);
        a = c * (1 - (d * k));
        m = c * (1 - (d * (1 - k)));
        switch (h) {
            case 0:
                e = c;
                g = m;
                l = b;
                break;
            case 1:
                e = a;
                g = c;
                l = b;
                break;
            case 2:
                e = b;
                g = c;
                l = m;
                break;
            case 3:
                e = b;
                g = a;
                l = c;
                break;
            case 4:
                e = m;
                g = b;
                l = c;
                break;
            case 5:
                e = c;
                g = b;
                l = a;
                break
        }
        return [e, g, l]
    }

    function RGB2HSB(c, d, k) {
        var j, h, e, g, b, a;
        j = Math.min(Math.min(c, d), k);
        a = Math.max(Math.max(c, d), k);
        if (j == a) {
            return [0, 0, a * 100]
        }
        h = (c == j) ? d - k : ((d == j) ? k - c : c - d);
        e = (c == j) ? 3 : ((d == j) ? 5 : 1);
        g = Math.floor((e - h / (a - j)) * 60) % 360;
        b = Math.floor(((a - j) / a) * 100);
        a = Math.floor(a * 100);
        return [g, b, a]
    }

    function ColorSelector(a) {
        this.init(a)
    }

    ColorSelector.prototype = {
        container: null,
        color: [0, 0, 0],
        hueSelector: null,
        luminosity: null,
        luminosityData: null,
        luminositySelector: null,
        luminosityPosition: null,
        dispatcher: null,
        changeEvent: null,

        init: function(k) {
            var m = this,
                b1, g2, d3;

            this.container = document.getElementById('mainDiv')
            this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", l, false);
            this.container.addEventListener("touchstart", f, false);


            g2 = document.getElementById('g2');
            g2.width = k.width;
            g2.height = k.height;

            b1 = g2.getContext("2d");
            b1.drawImage(k, 0, 0, g2.width, g2.height);
            d3 = b1.getImageData(0, 0, g2.width, g2.height).data;
            

            this.luminosity = document.getElementById('luminosity');
            this.hueSelector = document.getElementById('hue-selector');
            this.hueSelector.style.left = ((g2.width - 15) / 2) + "px";
            this.hueSelector.style.top = ((g2.height - 15) / 2) + "px";


            b1 = this.hueSelector.getContext("2d");
            b1.lineWidth = 2;
            b1.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
            b1.beginPath();
            b1.arc(8, 8, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            b1.stroke();
            b1.strokeStyle = "rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8)";
            b1.beginPath();
            b1.arc(7, 7, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            b1.stroke();
            
            this.luminosityPosition = [(k.width - 15), (k.height - 15) / 2];


            this.luminositySelector = document.getElementById('luminosity-selector');
            this.luminositySelector.style.left = (this.luminosityPosition[0] - 7) + "px";
            this.luminositySelector.style.top = (this.luminosityPosition[1] - 7) + "px";
            b1 = this.luminositySelector.getContext("2d");
            b1.drawImage(this.hueSelector, 0, 0, this.luminositySelector.width, this.luminositySelector.height);

            this.dispatcher = document.createElement("div");
            this.changeEvent = document.createEvent("Events");
            this.changeEvent.initEvent("change", true, true);

            function l(n) {
                window.addEventListener("mousemove", c, false);
                window.addEventListener("mouseup", h, false);
                e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
            }

            function c(n) {
                e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
            }

            function h(n) {
                window.removeEventListener("mousemove", c, false);
                window.removeEventListener("mouseup", h, false);
                e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
            }

            function f(n) {
                if (n.touches.length == 1) {
                    n.preventDefault();
                    window.addEventListener("touchmove", a, false);
                    window.addEventListener("touchend", j, false);
                    e(n.touches[0].pageX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.touches[0].pageY - m.container.offsetTop)
                }
            }

            function a(n) {
                if (n.touches.length == 1) {
                    n.preventDefault();
                    e(n.touches[0].pageX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.touches[0].pageY - m.container.offsetTop)
                }
            }

            function j(n) {
                if (n.touches.length == 0) {
                    n.preventDefault();
                    window.removeEventListener("touchmove", a, false);
                    window.removeEventListener("touchend", j, false)
                }
            }

            function e(o, t) {
                var q, p, r, n, s;
                q = o - 125;
                p = t - 125;
                r = Math.sqrt(q * q + p * p);
                if (r < 90) {
                    m.hueSelector.style.left = (o - 7) + "px";
                    m.hueSelector.style.top = (t - 7) + "px";
                    m.updateLuminosity([d3[(o + (t * 250)) * 4], d3[(o + (t * 250)) * 4 + 1], d3[(o + (t * 250)) * 4 + 2]])
                } else {
                    if (r > 100) {
                        n = q / r;
                        s = p / r;
                        m.luminosityPosition[0] = (n * 110) + 125;
                        m.luminosityPosition[1] = (s * 110) + 125;
                        m.luminositySelector.style.left = (m.luminosityPosition[0] - 7) + "px";
                        m.luminositySelector.style.top = (m.luminosityPosition[1] - 7) + "px"
                    }
                }
                o = Math.floor(m.luminosityPosition[0]);
                t = Math.floor(m.luminosityPosition[1]);
                m.color[0] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * 250)) * 4];
                m.color[1] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * 250)) * 4 + 1];
                m.color[2] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * 250)) * 4 + 2];
                m.dispatchEvent(m.changeEvent)
            }
        },
        getColor: function() {
            return this.color
        },
        setColor: function(c) {
            var a, e, f, d, b = Math.PI / 180;
            this.color = c;
            a = RGB2HSB(c[0] / 255, c[1] / 255, c[2] / 255);
            e = a[0] * b;
            f = (a[1] / 100) * 90;
            this.hueSelector.style.left = ((Math.cos(e) * f + 125) - 7) + "px";
            this.hueSelector.style.top = ((Math.sin(e) * f + 125) - 7) + "px";
            d = HSB2RGB(a[0], a[1], 100);
            d[0] *= 255;
            d[1] *= 255;
            d[2] *= 255;
            this.updateLuminosity(d);
            e = (a[2] / 100) * 360 * b;
            this.luminosityPosition[0] = (Math.cos(e) * 110) + 125;
            this.luminosityPosition[1] = (Math.sin(e) * 110) + 125;
            this.luminositySelector.style.left = (this.luminosityPosition[0] - 7) + "px";
            this.luminositySelector.style.top = (this.luminosityPosition[1] - 7) + "px";
            this.dispatchEvent(this.changeEvent)
        },
        updateLuminosity: function(j) {
            var d, f, l, g, p, b, a, o = 100,
                h = 120,
                k, n = 1080 / 2,
                e = 1 / n,
                c = Math.PI / 180,
                m = (n / 360);
            b = this.luminosity.width / 2;
            a = this.luminosity.height / 2;
            d = this.luminosity.getContext("2d");
            d.lineWidth = 3;
            d.clearRect(0, 0, this.luminosity.width, this.luminosity.height);
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                f = k / m * c;
                l = Math.cos(f);
                g = Math.sin(f);
                p = 255 - (k * e) * 255;
                d.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + Math.floor(j[0] - p) + "," + Math.floor(j[1] - p) + "," + Math.floor(j[2] - p) + ")";
                d.beginPath();
                d.moveTo(l * o + b, g * o + a);
                d.lineTo(l * h + b, g * h + a);
                d.stroke()
            }
            this.luminosityData = d.getImageData(0, 0, this.luminosity.width, this.luminosity.height).data
        },
        addEventListener: function(b, c, a) {
            this.dispatcher.addEventListener(b, c, a)
        },
        dispatchEvent: function(a) {
            this.dispatcher.dispatchEvent(a)
        },
        removeEventListener: function(b, c, a) {
            this.dispatcher.removeEventListener(b, c, a)
        }
    };

    function Palette() {
        var canvas, canvasCtx, canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfHeight, n = 90,
            m = 1080,
            f = 1 / m,
            l = m / 360,
            c = Math.PI / 180,
            j, h, k, g, canvasGradient;
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 250;
        canvas.height = 250;
        canvasHalfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
        canvasHalfHeight = canvas.height / 2;
        canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvasCtx.lineWidth = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            h = j / l * c;
            k = Math.cos(h);
            g = Math.sin(h);
            canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + Math.floor((j * f) * 360) + ", 100%, 50%)";
            canvasCtx.beginPath();
            canvasCtx.moveTo(k + canvasHalfWidth, g + canvasHalfHeight);
            canvasCtx.lineTo(k * n + canvasHalfWidth, g * n + canvasHalfHeight);
            canvasCtx.stroke()
        }
        canvasGradient = canvasCtx.createRadialGradient(canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfWidth, 0, canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfWidth, n);
        canvasGradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
        canvasGradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
        canvasCtx.fillStyle = canvasGradient;
        canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        return canvas
    }
    /* ADDED END */

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
        COLOR = [0, 0, 0],
        i,
        container, foregroundColorSelector, canvas, flattenCanvas, context;
    init();

    function init() {
        var hash, palette;
        container = document.createElement("div");

        document.body.appendChild(container);
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 250;//SCREEN_WIDTH;
        canvas.height = 250;//SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        container.appendChild(canvas);
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        palette = new Palette();
        foregroundColorSelector = new ColorSelector(palette);
        foregroundColorSelector.addEventListener("change", onForegroundColorSelectorChange, false);
        container.appendChild(foregroundColorSelector.container);

        foregroundColorSelector.setColor(COLOR);
        fillBox(COLOR);
    }

    function onForegroundColorSelectorChange(a) {
        fillBox(foregroundColorSelector.getColor());
    }

    function fillBox(color) {
        $('#selected-color').css('background-color', 'rgb('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+')');
    }
```

```css
#mainDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    z-index: 3;
}

#luminosity {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px;    
}

#hue-selector {
    position: absolute; 
}

#luminosity-selector {
    position: absolute; 
}

#selected-color {
    background-color: #000000; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
            <canvas id='g2'></canvas>
            <canvas id='luminosity' width='250' height='250'></canvas>
            <canvas id='hue-selector' width='15' height='15'></canvas>
            <canvas id='luminosity-selector' width='15' height='15'></canvas>     
        </div>

<div id='selected-color'></div>
```

Comment: This look like unminimized code to me.. do you have a different version with more descriptive variable names? It's also a bit unclear what the problem is, if the image is too large just scale it down to the size you need.

Comment: I don't have i only found compressed :/

Comment: The problem here is that the size has been hard coded. Essentially, you should be able to replace every instance of the number `250` with something like `palleteSize`. Just make sure you instantiate `palleteSize` before any of the rest of the code runs and you should be fine. I hope this helped.

Comment: i try all 250 change with new size but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHAT YEAR IS IT!?!?! Yeah, that took WAY too much effort...

But I did it! Just call `init(200)` and it will make a palette of size 200. It's default is 250 if you don't give it a size.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #mainDiv {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 125px;
                height: 125px; 
                cursor: pointer; 
                z-index: 3;
            }

            #luminosity {
                position: absolute; 
                left: 0px; 
                top: 0px;    
            }

            #hue-selector {
                position: absolute; 
            }

            #luminosity-selector {
                position: absolute; 
            }

            #selected-color {
                background-color: #000000; 
                width: 20px; 
                height: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id='mainDiv'>
            <canvas id='g2'></canvas>
            <canvas id='luminosity'></canvas>
            <canvas id='hue-selector'></canvas>
            <canvas id='luminosity-selector'></canvas>     
        </div>

        <div id='selected-color'></div>
        <script>

var paletteSize = 100;

function HSB2RGB(j, d, c) {
    var e, g, l, h, k, b, a, m;
    if (c == 0) {
        return [0, 0, 0]
    }
    j *= 0.016666667;
    d *= 0.01;
    c *= 0.01;
    h = Math.floor(j);
    k = j - h;
    b = c * (1 - d);
    a = c * (1 - (d * k));
    m = c * (1 - (d * (1 - k)));
    switch (h) {
        case 0:
            e = c;
            g = m;
            l = b;
            break;
        case 1:
            e = a;
            g = c;
            l = b;
            break;
        case 2:
            e = b;
            g = c;
            l = m;
            break;
        case 3:
            e = b;
            g = a;
            l = c;
            break;
        case 4:
            e = m;
            g = b;
            l = c;
            break;
        case 5:
            e = c;
            g = b;
            l = a;
            break
    }
    return [e, g, l]
}

function RGB2HSB(c, d, k) {
    var j, h, e, g, b, a;
    j = Math.min(Math.min(c, d), k);
    a = Math.max(Math.max(c, d), k);
    if (j == a) {
        return [0, 0, a * 100]
    }
    h = (c == j) ? d - k : ((d == j) ? k - c : c - d);
    e = (c == j) ? 3 : ((d == j) ? 5 : 1);
    g = Math.floor((e - h / (a - j)) * 60) % 360;
    b = Math.floor(((a - j) / a) * 100);
    a = Math.floor(a * 100);
    return [g, b, a]
}

function ColorSelector(a) {
    this.init(a)
}

ColorSelector.prototype = {
    container: null,
    color: [0, 0, 0],
    hueSelector: null,
    luminosity: null,
    luminosityData: null,
    luminositySelector: null,
    luminosityPosition: null,
    dispatcher: null,
    changeEvent: null,

    init: function(k) {
        var m = this,
            b1, g2, d3;

        this.container = document.getElementById('mainDiv')
        this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", l, false);
        this.container.addEventListener("touchstart", f, false);


        g2 = document.getElementById('g2');
        g2.width = k.width;
        g2.height = k.height;

        b1 = g2.getContext("2d");
        b1.drawImage(k, 0, 0, g2.width, g2.height);
        d3 = b1.getImageData(0, 0, g2.width, g2.height).data;


        this.luminosity = document.getElementById('luminosity');
        this.hueSelector = document.getElementById('hue-selector');
        this.hueSelector.style.left = ((g2.width - paletteSize*15/250) / 2) + "px";
        this.hueSelector.style.top = ((g2.height - paletteSize*15/250) / 2) + "px";


        b1 = this.hueSelector.getContext("2d");
        b1.lineWidth = 2;
        b1.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        b1.beginPath();
        b1.arc(paletteSize*8/250, paletteSize*8/250, paletteSize*6/250, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        b1.stroke();
        b1.strokeStyle = "rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8)";
        b1.beginPath();
        b1.arc(paletteSize*7/250, paletteSize*7/250, paletteSize*6/250, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        b1.stroke();

        this.luminosityPosition = [(k.width - paletteSize*15/250), (k.height - paletteSize*15/250) / 2];


        this.luminositySelector = document.getElementById('luminosity-selector');
        this.luminositySelector.style.left = (this.luminosityPosition[0] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
        this.luminositySelector.style.top = (this.luminosityPosition[1] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
        b1 = this.luminositySelector.getContext("2d");
        b1.drawImage(this.hueSelector, 0, 0, this.luminositySelector.width, this.luminositySelector.height);

        this.dispatcher = document.createElement("div");
        this.changeEvent = document.createEvent("Events");
        this.changeEvent.initEvent("change", true, true);

        function l(n) {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", c, false);
            window.addEventListener("mouseup", h, false);
            e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
        }

        function c(n) {
            e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
        }

        function h(n) {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", c, false);
            window.removeEventListener("mouseup", h, false);
            e(n.clientX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.clientY - m.container.offsetTop)
        }

        function f(n) {
            if (n.touches.length == 1) {
                n.preventDefault();
                window.addEventListener("touchmove", a, false);
                window.addEventListener("touchend", j, false);
                e(n.touches[0].pageX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.touches[0].pageY - m.container.offsetTop)
            }
        }

        function a(n) {
            if (n.touches.length == 1) {
                n.preventDefault();
                e(n.touches[0].pageX - m.container.offsetLeft, n.touches[0].pageY - m.container.offsetTop)
            }
        }

        function j(n) {
            if (n.touches.length == 0) {
                n.preventDefault();
                window.removeEventListener("touchmove", a, false);
                window.removeEventListener("touchend", j, false)
            }
        }

        function e(o, t) {
            var q, p, r, n, s;
            q = o - paletteSize/2;
            p = t - paletteSize/2;
            r = Math.sqrt(q * q + p * p);
            if (r < paletteSize*90/250) {
                m.hueSelector.style.left = (o - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
                m.hueSelector.style.top = (t - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
                m.updateLuminosity([d3[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4], d3[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4 + 1], d3[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4 + 2]])
            } else {
                if (r > paletteSize*100/250) {
                    n = q / r;
                    s = p / r;
                    m.luminosityPosition[0] = (n * paletteSize*110/250) + paletteSize/2;
                    m.luminosityPosition[1] = (s * paletteSize*110/250) + paletteSize/2;
                    m.luminositySelector.style.left = (m.luminosityPosition[0] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
                    m.luminositySelector.style.top = (m.luminosityPosition[1] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px"
                }
            }
            o = Math.floor(m.luminosityPosition[0]);
            t = Math.floor(m.luminosityPosition[1]);
            m.color[0] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4];
            m.color[1] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4 + 1];
            m.color[2] = m.luminosityData[(o + (t * paletteSize)) * 4 + 2];
            m.dispatchEvent(m.changeEvent)
        }
    },
    getColor: function() {
        return this.color
    },
    setColor: function(c) {
        var a, e, f, d, b = Math.PI / 180;
        this.color = c;
        a = RGB2HSB(c[0] / 255, c[1] / 255, c[2] / 255);
        e = a[0] * b;
        f = (a[1] / 100) * 90;
        this.hueSelector.style.left = ((Math.cos(e) * f + paletteSize/2) - 7) + "px";
        this.hueSelector.style.top = ((Math.sin(e) * f + paletteSize/2) - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
        d = HSB2RGB(a[0], a[1], 100);
        d[0] *= 255;
        d[1] *= 255;
        d[2] *= 255;
        this.updateLuminosity(d);
        e = (a[2] / 100) * 360 * b;
        this.luminosityPosition[0] = (Math.cos(e) * paletteSize*110/250) + paletteSize/2;
        this.luminosityPosition[1] = (Math.sin(e) * paletteSize*110/250) + paletteSize/2;
        this.luminositySelector.style.left = (this.luminosityPosition[0] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
        this.luminositySelector.style.top = (this.luminosityPosition[1] - paletteSize*7/250) + "px";
        this.dispatchEvent(this.changeEvent)
    },
    updateLuminosity: function(j) {
        var d, f, l, g, p, b, a, o = paletteSize*100/250,
            h = paletteSize*120/250,
            k, n = paletteSize*1080/250 / 2,
            e = 1 / n,
            c = Math.PI / 180,
            m = (n / 360);
        b = this.luminosity.width / 2;
        a = this.luminosity.height / 2;
        d = this.luminosity.getContext("2d");
        d.lineWidth = 3;
        d.clearRect(0, 0, this.luminosity.width, this.luminosity.height);
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            f = k / m * c;
            l = Math.cos(f);
            g = Math.sin(f);
            p = 255 - (k * e) * 255;
            d.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + Math.floor(j[0] - p) + "," + Math.floor(j[1] - p) + "," + Math.floor(j[2] - p) + ")";
            d.beginPath();
            d.moveTo(l * o + b, g * o + a);
            d.lineTo(l * h + b, g * h + a);
            d.stroke()
        }
        this.luminosityData = d.getImageData(0, 0, this.luminosity.width, this.luminosity.height).data
    },
    addEventListener: function(b, c, a) {
        this.dispatcher.addEventListener(b, c, a)
    },
    dispatchEvent: function(a) {
        this.dispatcher.dispatchEvent(a)
    },
    removeEventListener: function(b, c, a) {
        this.dispatcher.removeEventListener(b, c, a)
    }
};

function Palette() {
    var canvas, canvasCtx, canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfHeight, n = paletteSize*90/250,
        m = 1080,
        f = 1 / m,
        l = m / 360,
        c = Math.PI / 180,
        j, h, k, g, canvasGradient;
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = paletteSize;
    canvas.height = paletteSize;
    canvasHalfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
    canvasHalfHeight = canvas.height / 2;
    canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        h = j / l * c;
        k = Math.cos(h);
        g = Math.sin(h);
        canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + Math.floor((j * f) * 360) + ", 100%, 50%)";
        canvasCtx.beginPath();
        canvasCtx.moveTo(k + canvasHalfWidth, g + canvasHalfHeight);
        canvasCtx.lineTo(k * n + canvasHalfWidth, g * n + canvasHalfHeight);
        canvasCtx.stroke()
    }
    canvasGradient = canvasCtx.createRadialGradient(canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfWidth, 0, canvasHalfWidth, canvasHalfWidth, n);
    canvasGradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
    canvasGradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
    canvasCtx.fillStyle = canvasGradient;
    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return canvas
}
/* ADDED END */

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    COLOR = [0, 0, 0],
    i,
    container, foregroundColorSelector, canvas, flattenCanvas, context;
init();

function init(newPaletteSize) {

    paletteSize = newPaletteSize || 250;

    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    mainDiv.width = paletteSize/2;
    mainDiv.height = paletteSize/2;

    var luminosity = document.getElementById('luminosity');
    luminosity.width = paletteSize;
    luminosity.height = paletteSize;

    var hueselector = document.getElementById('hue-selector');
    hueselector.width = paletteSize*15/250;
    hueselector.height = paletteSize*15/250;

    var luminosityselector = document.getElementById('luminosity-selector');
    luminosityselector.width = paletteSize*15/250;
    luminosityselector.height = paletteSize*15/250;

    var selectedcolor = document.getElementById('selected-color');
    selectedcolor.style.width = paletteSize*20/250;
    selectedcolor.style.height = paletteSize*20/250;

    var hash, palette;
    container = document.createElement("div");

    document.body.appendChild(container);
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = paletteSize;//SCREEN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = paletteSize;//SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    container.appendChild(canvas);
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    palette = new Palette();
    foregroundColorSelector = new ColorSelector(palette);
    foregroundColorSelector.addEventListener("change", onForegroundColorSelectorChange, false);
    container.appendChild(foregroundColorSelector.container);

    foregroundColorSelector.setColor(COLOR);
    fillBox(COLOR);
}

function onForegroundColorSelectorChange(a) {
    fillBox(foregroundColorSelector.getColor());
}

function fillBox(color) {
    $('#selected-color').css('background-color', 'rgb('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+')');
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment about it, but I'll try and make an answer too.

Basically, your main issue here is that this code wasn't written to be flexible. It was written to have a very specific size and your code always assumes that the size isn't changing. To manipulate the size of the Palette, you will have to replace **EVERY** instance of a hard coded value (or "magic number") that is related to a size. You need to update your code to be a bit more "dynamic."

You can simply pass `Palette` a size. In order to establish an initial size for the palette to take.
Example: `palette = new Palette(200);`

Of course you have to update the `Palette` function

```
function Palette(paletteSize) {
    ...
    /* Previously *
    canvas.width = 250;
    canvas.height = 250;

    /* Now it is */
    canvas.width = paletteSize;
    canvas.height = paletteSize;
    ...
}
```

And the rest of the code too.

For example, a snippet from the `updateLuminosity` function:

```
...
var d, f, l, g, p, b, a, o = 100,
    h = 120,
    k, n = 1080 / 2,
    e = 1 / n,
    c = Math.PI / 180,
    m = (n / 360);
    b = this.luminosity.width / 2;
    a = this.luminosity.height / 2;

d.moveTo(l * o + b, g * o + a);
d.lineTo(l * h + b, g * h + a);
...
```

As far as I can tell, `o` and `h` are the inner and outer radii, respectively, of the luminosity ring. You would have to change those values to something to the effect of `o = paletteSize*100/250`. You have already selected a preferred luminosity ring according to the size of the palette (`100` for a palette of `250`). Multiplying `100/250` by `paletteSize` will always retain that ratio. You can apply this principle to other variables that represent dimensions in order to quickly update your code base without compromising the current layout.

Hopefully this gives you a good enough idea of what to change. Best of luck!

EDIT: I have a page that demonstrates the "flexibility of dynamic sizing." [Open this in a new window and Re-size the height and width.](http://crzyman.github.io/ClassClock)

Comment: i try a lot changing values but, cannot get good result i think i need more effort to find not compress code source it's better way

Comment: I added a new answer. It contains the fix you were looking for. I prefer to not do this, but you said you were having trouble.